# F# - how can I create an n-tuple from an n-1 tuple and a 1

Tags: f#, tuples

say I've got a tuple:

```
let t = (1,'a')
```

and I want to create a triple/3-tuple:

```
let createTriple (a,b) c =
    (a, b, c)
```

is there a syntax in F# where I can create an n-tuple from an n-1-tuple and a singular value?

```
let createNTuple (a..z) q =
    (a..z, q)
```

Comment: That's a good point - hopefully you're not trying to use a tuple as an arbitrarily long heterogeneous list? That would be a bad idea.

Comment: I wanted to create a function argument collector for auto-memoization on arbitrary argument numbers. So, for example a function int -> bool -> float would in effect generate another int -> bool -> float which would have an internal mapping of (int * bool) values to floats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking about stepping outside the type system, so sure you can do it through reflection, but not in a type-safe way.

```
let createNTuple tuple x =
    let fields = [|yield! FSharpValue.GetTupleFields(tuple); yield box x|]
    let fieldsTy = [|yield! FSharpType.GetTupleElements(tuple.GetType()); yield x.GetType()|]
    let ty = FSharpType.MakeTupleType(fieldsTy)
    FSharpValue.MakeTuple(fields, ty) |> unbox

let (a: int, b: char, c: string) = createNTuple (1, 'a') "foo"
```

Comment: This sounds roughly what I want - how would it interact with the rest of the code? As Amadan mentioned, there's no discernible signature for this function. Also, I'm guessing it's pretty slow?

Comment: Yes, reflection is slow, but "too slow" is up to you to decide. The signature is `'a -> 'b -> 'c` so the result type must be inferrable, which might require annotations as in my example.

Answer (score 2):

What I would suggest is defining a set of functions (perhaps as static members on a class, so that you can make use of overloading), that would handle appending to tuples in a type-safe way. Realistically, you should only need a 5- or 7-tuple at most, anything more feels like pushing it too far (though you can still try to handle those cases through reflection if you care).

Something like this:

```
type TupleAppender = 
    static member Append((a, b), x) = (a, b, x)
    static member Append((a, b, c), x) = (a, b, c, x)
    (* and so on *)
```

This is boilerplate, but at least you're within the type system.

Comment: Just for the fun of it: could you do this "dynamically", by creating a type-provider?

Answer (score 0):

No, what you're asking is impossible. What type signature would such a function have? As opposed to lists, tuples can have differently typed elements, but they are of fixed length - precisely because you need to know the type for each element. You can't specify a type for any n-element tuple. If you need variable-length structures, use a list.